# Android Download PDF Giving Download Unsuccessful

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android, nexus-5

I have been trying to figure out what this error is and how to get rid of it.

Whenever I try to open the pdf file from this website on chrome:

http://www.stdavidtheking.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=feature.display&feature_id=247

I get the error download unsuccesful. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54805/how-to-open-pdf-from-notification-bar-and-fix-cannot-open-file-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous experience, I've always had problems downloading with Chrome. I'd try a different browser like [Boat Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatbrowser.free) or [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens to me in Chrome. What seems to work better is, instead of tapping on the link to the PDF, long-press on the link and choose Save link.

Comment: It works, thank you! This is very old Android bug, that has not been fixed. See in official Android bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19951